# Maximum number of connection pool in gremlin server

Tags: tinkerpop, gremlin-server

Does anyone know the maximum number of connection pool that can be simultaneously opened in gremlin server, version 3.3 and the latest version respectively?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is an absolute answer to this question. The "maximum size" is dependent on the available resources allotted to Gremlin Server and the workload being sent to it for processing. Some tuning options are described in the [Reference Documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_tuning) but you will need to run tests to find out what works best in your situation and what your own maximum setting will be to yield you the best performance.